# list currently connected computers in a combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

I want to display all TCP currently connected computers in a combobox, so the user is able to choose which computer in the network to send a message to, using the combobox but not sure how to implement it.

```
public partial class WCF : Form
{
    public WCF()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void WCF_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceHost svc = new ServiceHost(typeof(ApplicationService));
        svc.Credentials.Peer.MeshPassword = "hehe";
        svc.Open();
    }
}


[ServiceContract]
public interface IApplicationService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void lol();
}

public class ApplicationService : IApplicationService
{
    public void lol()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("lol");
    }

}
```

}

So far I have a Winform that is able to connect to each other over TCP. I just need a way to display the established connections for all current clients in combobox1. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First create Arraylist object and each time you accept a new client connection, you must hold the socket for further handling.

```
        ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
        while (true)
        {
            Main_Client = Main_Listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            arr.Add(Main_Client);                                
        }
```

This will add every client connection in the combobox

```
        foreach (object obj in arr) 
        {                
            comboBox1.Items.Add(obj);
        }
```